Help with `font-lock-add-keywords` regex for org keywords
I am trying to add my own org 'document keywords' with my own faces. I am referring to the keywords sitting at the top of the file like #+title: My Tile for example which get their own faces.
Thanks to the doc and a few posts I found here, I managed to get close to what I am trying to achieve for the roamify keyword:
(defun org-roamify-font-lock-keywords ()
  "Add font-lock keywords for the roamify keyword."
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   '(("#\\+ROAMIFY:"
      (0
       'org-roamify-keyword
       prepend
       )))
   t)
  )

(add-hook! 'org-mode-hook #'org-roamify-font-lock-keywords)

It was a lot of error and trial to get there, so I simplifed the regex to make sure I was debugging my keyword adding attempts.
This "#\\+ROAMIFY:" changes the face of the keyword's KEY and not its VALUE. I am obviously trying to do the opposite. I tried a lot of different things, the latest being "^#\\+ROAMIFY:[ \t]*\$.*\$$" which I have difficulties to understand myself.
My understanding of what I am doing is shaky, and I kind of suck at regex (in all languages and flavors). I did change the 'substring' match value to 1, but further than that I am not sure I am only debugging the regex, or if it affects other parameters of the function.
Anyway I would appreciate some pointers to make sure I get a working regex and get back to debugging if need to be. Thanks in advance.

I would approach it from the other end: find out the faces that are used in whatever keyword line you'd like to emulate (e.g. on #+TITLE: foo, put your cursor on a T and do C-u C-x = to find out that the keyword uses the face org-document-info-keyword and ditto on the f to find out that the value uses the face org-document-title). Then I would search the sources for these faces and see how they are used, then emulate what the Org code is doing.

Thanks for some great tips. That is how I started actually, but the faces only brought me to a defface function. I could not get any further from there, I tried ripgreping through emacs.d for a line containing keywords, faces, font-lock functions with no luck. I would love to find the source for this actually. That is why I decided to give font-lock-add-keyword a try. With the help of other posts, it was not so bad to make it work in principle. I think only the regex is missing. I am going to to give it another try later, thanks again.

That's the definition of the face. You are interested in how the face is used. Try org-fontify-meta-lines-and-blocks-1 in org.el.

Thanks, org-fontify-meta-lines-and-blocks-1 is exactly the function I was looking for. My current understanding of  re-search or advanced string-match type of Elisp code is not enough yet for me to use that  code. I will make a note to keep coming back to it until it is though. In the meantime I will try to get a regex to work with the snippet I posted if it is even possible. I will edit my post if I meke any progress.
